# Adding a KeyValue List OR Dictionary to a DBInterface

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, interface

I have the following interface that is used to update the database

```
public interface IMydDataContext : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<TEntity, TKrey> GetRepository<TEntity, TKrey>() where TEntity : class, IDomainObject<TKrey>;
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity, TKey>() where TEntity : class, IDomainObject<TKey>;
    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The GetRepository function is used with my _DataContext which is defined as such:

```
private IMydDataContext _dataContext;
```

and is used in the following manner:

```
 var newGroup = new Group
        {

            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Key = DiContainer.GetInstance<IEntityKeyGeneratorService>().Generate(request.Name),
            Name = name,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
            CreatedById = GetUserIdFromHttpContext().ToString()
        };

_dataContext.GetRepository<Group, Guid>().Insert(newGroup);
```

For purposes of efficiency I have created a KeyValuePair list that can hold several iterations of newGroup(So that I may push them to the DB all at once):

```
List<KeyValuePair<Group, Guid>> _dataContextList = new List<KeyValuePair<Group, Guid>>();

_dataContextList.Insert(0,new KeyValuePair<Group,Guid>(newGroup, newGroup.Id));
```

My Question is:

How do I use this new KeyValuePair List "_dataContextList" with "GetReposititory" or the IMYDataContext class in general?

I want to give my _dataContextList the same ability as the vanilla _dataContext so that it can send each one of it's values to the DB in the same way and to the same place.

Comment: You would have to create some special `IList<T>` that will internally synchronize its items using `_dataContext`. But you already expose `IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity, TKey>() where TEntity : class, IDomainObject<TKey>;` in your interface, so why would you want to create some special class that will essentially mirror it? Or I don't exactly understand your problem - perhaps you should add some example of what do you want to achieve with such `_dataContextList`.

Comment: @EugenePodskal so `_dataContext` saves to the DB with the following  code: `_dataContext.GetRepository<Group, Guid>().Insert(newGroup);`   this basically adds a `newGroup` to the DB with the keyvalue combo of `Group` and `Guid`. I want to send `_dataContextList` to the db via `GetRepository` as well.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to have a collection that will push items to the database just as they are inserted, or what? Give some code sample of how would the thing you want to achieve look like - for example: `_dataContextList.Insert(key, item)` internally uses `_dataContext.GetRepository<Group, Guid>().Insert(item)` or whatever.

Comment: So @EugenePodskal I would ideally like to have something like this: `_dataContextList.GetRepository<newGroup, newGroup.Id>().Insert(newGroup)` the idea being that my _dataContextList is using 'GetRepository' also I understand I might need to add a `foreach` to that as well but right now I just need to be able to pass my `_dataContextList` to the DB via `GetRepository`

Comment: @EugenePodskal said: Do you want to have a collection that will push items to the database just as they are inserted? YES! :) along the lines of the code snippet above.

Comment: Then just store the `_dataContext` in your collection and use it in collection's `GetRepository` method. Though it is a code smell in my opinion - while collection may be able to internally push its items to some outer store, the same collection having `GetRepository` seems to be at odds with principle of information hiding and partially with SRP.

Comment: In any case I recommend create a new more clear and to the point question (it took quite a long time to at least partially understand what you want and it is still too fuzzy in my opinion). Just make sure that it is clear not only to you, but to the [programmer's best friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) as well.

Comment: @EugenePodskal `_dataContextList` is a list that holds all the `newGroup`. I want to then use `GetRepository` on EACH of the `newGroup` inside the `_dataContextLis` thereby sending them to the DB. Thats the rubber ducky explanation best as I can give it :) with my limited knowledge.

Comment: I am sure that I have given to you enough advises about how to do it. But in my opinion there is nothing you will get from some supersmart collection, so I'd personally stick to the simple dummy collection and some method on `IRepository<TEntity, TKrey>` that allows to insert that collection as one. That's all.